# laravel multiple domains csrf tokenmismatch

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, multiple-domains

Im building a system with two domains (sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com). These two domains use the exact same system. The only reason i use two domains is because of the name to make things more clear for the users.

On sub1.domain.com everything works fine, but on sub2.domain.com i get a CSRF TokenMismatch error.

I've tried to implement CORS in two different ways, making [my own middleware](https://blog.nikhilben.com/2015/09/02/laravel5-rest-api-and-cors/) and using a [standard composer package for laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors).
Those two solutions do not seem to work.

I also tried to define a domain in `config/session.php`. (sub-domains and top-level domain). But when i tried that, the whole login stopped working and i was redirected back to the login page without a message. (I did received a error message when used wrong credentials)

Some ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's exactly what CSRF is protecting from I believe. It's either protect yourself from CSRF or have it work your way.

Comment: Yeah, but they use the exact same code base, it is just a second domain name. It are two vHosts linked to the same directory. I thought that the csrf logic would be the same on both sides. The csrf also works on my local domain, and my public domain without changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, for one domain the csrf is working but for another one I am receiving connection timeout. The only solution I found is to add exceptions for CSRF verification in VerifyCSRFTtoken controller. My controller looks like that right now:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
   protected $except = [
    '/routename',
   ];
}
```

This is not the best solution, but as a fast fix is ok. Looking for better ideas.